# Python 3.3.3 on Macbook pro, can't open IDLE at all

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, python

I'm having trouble with running python on my Macbook Pro OS X 10.9.1.

Two days ago it was running with absolutely no problem and now it won't start up.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, and update the Tkinter and Tcl/Tk etc.

It appears in the dock for a second then disappears. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See [this important note](http://www.python.org/getit/mac/tcltk/) on the official Python website about Tcl/Tk and IDLE on Mac OS X. You should install a third-party version of Tcl/Tkl to solve your problem.

> Python's integrated development environment, IDLE, and the tkinter GUI
>   toolkit it uses, depend on the Tk GUI toolkit which is not part of
>   Python itself. For best results, it is important that the proper
>   release of Tcl/Tk is installed on your machine.
>
> *[...]*
>
> If you are using Python from a python.org 64-bit/32-bit Python
>   installer for Mac OS X 10.6 and later, you should only use IDLE or
>   tkinter with an updated third-party Tcl/Tk 8.5, like ActiveTcl 8.5
>   installed.
>
> If you are using OS X 10.9 Mavericks and a Python from a python.org
>   64-bit/32-bit installer, application windows may not update properly
>   due to a Tk problem. Install the latest ActiveTcl 8.5.15.0 if
>   possible. (Also, a critical OS X 10.9 problem that could cause Python
>   to crash when used interactively has been fixed in the current 3.3.3,
>   2.7.6, and pre-release 3.4.0 64-bit/32-bit installers.)

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt cycle power.

Then if IDLE continues to not start:

When you uninstalled did you delete the savedState file from:

~/Library/Saved Application State/

If not try using AppCleaner to delete everything associated with IDLE and reinstall.

One other thing to think of: Have you moved or renamed the working folder? Some apps don't like it when you move/rename their folder.

You could also try an earlier version (assuming you have the latest version, if not try that) and see if it will run.